# How to align to elements side by side?

Tags: html, css

I have a video and a css animation, I want the video to be centred and the animation to the left. I tried floating them but this left a big gap in between them. - codepen - https://codepen.io/MarkHarrison/pen/xpZLLy

```
iframe{
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-image-source: url(https://i.imgur.com/91tJ1qi.png);
    border-image-slice: 10;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    display: block;
    width: 600px;
    height: 420px;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Is this the final effect you want? https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/ppgLXE

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] (in form of a Stack Snippet) directly to your question? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. add "position: relative" to the .wrapper
   // don't 2. remove % margin-top from .box
2. add magic css to .box

   position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: calc(50% - 520px);
      transform: translateX(-50%);

// dont' 4. adjust top with em/px so that the image fits vertically
use transform: translateY() for that instead